# The data types varchar and int are incompatible in the concat operator

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been stuck for the past two days execute it give the error:

> The data types varchar and int are incompatible in the concat operator

Here is my table:

```
create table salestable
(
     id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, 
     empid char(5), 
     datesold date, 
     monthonly varchar(50), 
     amount money
)
```

This code inserts the dummy record into `dbo.salestable` for working in salestable, debug and step into the code that give the debug and understanding code

```
declare @outercounter int = 1
declare @innercounter int = 1

while @outercounter <= (select count(name) from namestable)
begin 
    while @innercounter <= datediff(day, getdate() -datepart(day, getdate()), {fn concat('12/31/',Datepart(year,getdate()))})
    begin 
        insert into salestable (empid, datesold, monthonly, amount) 
        values (@outercounter, 
                getdate() - datepart(day, getdate()) + @innercounter,
                Datename(month, getdate() - datepart(day, getdate()) + @innercounter),
                rand() * 10000)
        set @innercounter =  @innercounter +1           
    end

    set @outercounter = @outercounter + 1
    set @innercounter = 1
end

select * from dbo.salestable
```

Comment: I'm counteracting someone's upvote with a downvote, as the first version of this was not well formatted, and we discourage txtspk here. Please write questions as carefully as possible - the more readable and detailed they are, the more likely you are to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn concat('12/31/',CAST(Datepart(year,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)))
```

Try this