# SQL Concat multiple columns + "|" for Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, concatenation

Trying to concatenate columns and pipes(|) to create first left outer join.

```
dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry].MapValue = the concatenated values of 3 columns with pipes in between
```

My query:

```
SELECT dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_] AS Job, 
       dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task No_] AS [Cost Code], 
       dbo.[U1$Job Task].Description, 
       dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry].MapID
FROM   dbo.[U1$Job Task] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry] ON CONCAT(dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_], "|", dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task No_], "|", dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task Type]) = dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry].MapValue 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.U1$Job ON dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_] = dbo.U1$Job.No_
WHERE  (dbo.U1$Job.Status = 2)
```

> Error messages: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>  Invalid
>   column name '|'.
>  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name '|'.

In SSMS 2017 when creating a view, it tries to add a function command and changes "|" to [|].  I need the query to run in a view eventually.

Comment: SQL Server uses a single quote (`'`) for the literal string quote identifier not double quotes (`"`). Replace `"|"` (which is trying the reference a column with the name `|`) with `'|'`.

Comment: Not just SQL Server - double quotes are used for object names in the SQL standard. Different databases have their own special quotes, eg `[]` in SQL Server or ``` in MySQL. Both of them treat `"` as an object quote though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `""` are used for object names. Your query should be like below (replace the "|" by '|'):

```
SELECT dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_] AS Job, 
       dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task No_] AS [Cost Code], 
       dbo.[U1$Job Task].Description, 
       dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry].MapID
FROM   dbo.[U1$Job Task] LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry] 
ON concat( concat(concat (dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_], '|'), concat (dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task No_], '|')), dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job Task Type])= dbo.[SFI Barcode Entry].MapValue 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.U1$Job 
ON dbo.[U1$Job Task].[Job No_] = dbo.U1$Job.No_
WHERE (dbo.U1$Job.Status = 2)
```

Comment: This is really a typographical error more than anything. The comments actually give more detail here to the OP on why they were actually getting the error.

Comment: Why you need to write a nested `CONCAT()` there? Also I'd use some aliases there.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  What a pain...the new code returns an error saying the data types nvarchar and int are incompatible in the concat operator.

Comment: You should cast the numeric field (probably the [Job No_]) to varchar like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875174/the-data-types-varchar-and-int-are-incompatible-in-the-concat-operator

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Wrong, `CONCAT()` will cast the `INT` to `VARCHAR(n)`, so the issue isn't [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b59f3c52a8292e8117f54927161ea1d)